# Connectivity Manager unregisterNetworkCallBack already unregistered

Tags: java, android

In my android application I am unregistering a networkCallback onPause of an activity. There are times where I can get the error, Caused by

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
NetworkCallback was already unregistered
```

Is there a way to check if the network callback already was unregistered or to prevent "double" unregistering? Or registered so we known when to call unregister?

```
if (mNetworkCallback != null && mConnectivityManager != null) {
           try{
               mConnectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(mNetworkCallback);

           }
           catch (Exception e){
               Log.d(TAG, "unregister failed");
           }
        }
```

Comment: Where are you registering it? It should be `onResume` which compliments `onPause` in lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: I an registering the callback onResume @Mark

Comment: are you calling `onPause` directly?

Comment: No, it is not called programmatically anywhere. Note: This does not occur on every run, only sometimes.

Comment: Are you registering using your own `Handler` off the main thread? The only thing I can think of is a timing issue between registering and unregistering if `onResume` and `onPause` are called multiple times in quick succession. might be worth some logging to see - as suggested a try .. catch obviously works, but would be nice to know the underlying cause

Comment: Yes it is on the mainthread, okay i will try some logging to see if it is a timing issue,

Answer (score 9):

There is no method to check if the network is already unregistered.

1. Try to put your code in:

```
try{
    //your code
} 
catch (IllegalArgumentException exception){
    //network is already unregistered
}
```

2. Or simply you can handle it with boolean flag yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I just downgraded the version of Connectivity from 0.4.9+5 to 0.4.9+3 and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would work in Kotlin:

```kotlin
try {
    // Your code
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // i.e. NetworkCallback was already unregistered
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search the source code of android to see `unregisterNetworkCallback()` best practices [here](https://cs.android.com/search?q=unregisterNetworkCallback&sq=&ss=android).

It's actually very similar to what you currently have however you aren't setting your callback to `null` after unregister. Update your current code to this and it'll follow the pattern currently used in Android as per the above link and hopefully solve your issue.

```
if (mNetworkCallback != null && mConnectivityManager != null) {
   try{
       mConnectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(mNetworkCallback);
       // Added code: Set call back to null so this doesn't get called again.
       mNetworkCallback = null;
   }
   catch (Exception e){
       Log.d(TAG, "unregister failed");
   }
}
```