# No internet Connection Alert Dialog box. NetworkCallback was already unregistered error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a no internet connection alert dialog box on my app, it works but app crashes afterwards.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NetworkCallback was already unregistered

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private ConnectivityManager mCManager;
        private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback mCallback;
        private AlertDialog mDialog;
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            mCManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder().build();
            mCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLost(Network network) {
    
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)
                            .setTitle("Oops!... No Internet Connection")
                            .setMessage("Check your WIFI or your Mobile Data")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    
                                    finishAndRemoveTask();
                                }
                            });
    
                    mDialog = builder.show();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
    
                    if (mDialog != null) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            };
           
            mCManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, mCallback);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
    
            mCManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(mCallback);
            super.onStop();
        }
    
    }
```

I declared this in my application manifest as shown below.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Can someone please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connectivity Manager unregisterNetworkCallBack already unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935621/connectivity-manager-unregisternetworkcallback-already-unregistered)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're adding it in `onCreate`, but removing it in `onStop`.  Adding/removing listeners should be done in the matching methods:

- `onCreate`/`onDestroy`
- `onStart`/`onStop`
- `onResume`/`onPause`

Since you only want to show when the user has the app open, you probably want to register in `onStart` and unregister in `onStop`.  Just make sure to check if you want to display it initially in `onStart` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a try catch like thisto ignore the exception:

```java
try {
    mCManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(mCallback);
} catch(Exception e) {
    // ignore
}
```